# Trying to make battleship but String[][] board will not update properly

Tags: java

The `userGuess[y, x]` gets compared to `ship1[][]` but only updates the `board[][]` at the matching index with `"!"` when I enter a user guess that equals `(ship1[2][0], ship1[2][1])`.

In other words, I feed `updateBoard()` the `int[]` userGuess, `updateBoard` loops through the `int[][] ship1` and compares `userGuess[0]` to `ship1[0][0]` and `userGuess[1]` to `ship1[0][1]...ship1[2][0]`, `ship1[2][1]`, looking to see if they match, but the only match I am getting is if I enter a userGuess that equals the values at `(ship1[2][0], ship1[2][1])`.

Does anyone see what I have done wrong?

```java
package assignment_8;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Battleship {

    private String[][] board = new String[8][8];
    private int[][] ship1 = new int[3][2];
    private int[][] ship2 = new int[4][2];
    private int counter;

    Battleship() {
    }

    public void makeBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                board[i][j] = "| ";
                board[i][7] = "| |";
            }
        }
    }
    public void makeShips() {
        int ship1Y = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
        int ship1X = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
        int ship2Y = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
        int ship2X = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
        int coinToss = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
        if(coinToss == 1) {
            if(ship1X >= 5) {
                ship1X = 4;
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < ship1.length; i++) {
                ship1[i][0] = ship1Y;
                ship1[i][1] = ship1X + i;
            }
            if(ship2Y >= 4) {
                ship2Y = 3;
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < ship2.length; i++) {
                ship2[i][0] = ship2Y + i;
                ship2[i][1] = ship2X;
            }
        } else {
            if(ship1Y >= 5) {
                ship1Y = 4;
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < ship1.length; i++) {
                ship1[i][0] = ship1Y + i;
                ship1[i][1] = ship1X;
            }
            if(ship2X >= 4) {
                ship2X = 3;
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < ship2.length; i++) {
                ship2[i][0] = ship2Y;
                ship2[i][1] = ship2X + i;
            }
        }
    }
    public String[][] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }
    public int[][] getShip1() {
        return ship1;
    }
    public int[][] getShip2() {
        return ship2;
    }
    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public void updateBoard(int[] userInput) {
        for(int i = 0; i < ship1.length; i++) {
            if(ship1[i][0] == userInput[0] && ship1[i][1] == userInput[1] && board[userInput[0]][userInput[1]] == "| ") {
                counter++;
            } else if (ship1[i][0] == userInput[0] && ship1[i][1] == userInput[1] && board[userInput[0]][userInput[1]] == "| |") {
                counter++;
            }
            if(ship1[i][0] == userInput[0] && ship1[i][1] == userInput[1]) {
                board[userInput[0]][userInput[1]] = "|!";
                if(userInput[1] == 7) {
                    board[userInput[0]][userInput[1]] = "|!|";
                }
            } else {
                board[userInput[0]][userInput[1]] = "|X";
                if(userInput[1] == 7) {
                    board[userInput[0]][userInput[1]] = "|X|";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Battleship bs = new Battleship();
        bs.makeBoard();
        bs.makeShips();
        int[][] ship1 = bs.getShip1();
        //int[][] ship2 = bs.getShip2();
        for(int i = 0; i < ship1.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("[" + ship1[i][0] + "][" + ship1[i][1] + "]");
        }
        System.out.println();
        /*for(int i = 0; i < ship2.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("[" + ship2[i][0] + "][" + ship2[i][1] + "]");
        }*/
        System.out.println();
        int[] userGuess = new int[2];
        int counter = 0;
        String[][] board = bs.getBoard();
        do {
            for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(board[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            counter = bs.getCounter();
            System.out.println("Counter = " + counter);
            System.out.print("Enter Y coordinate (0 - 7): ");
            userGuess[0] = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter X coordinate(0 - 7): ");
            userGuess[1] = sc.nextInt();
            bs.updateBoard(userGuess);
            System.out.println();
        } while(counter < 8);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you step through this using a debugger, what is the *first* point at which it behaves differently than you expected?

Comment: I doesnt throw any errors, it just doesnt add an "!" where I expect it to

Comment: What is the first point at which it behaves differently than you expected?

Comment: update: didnt know what a dubugger was, I watched a video and am going to see if I can successfully use the eclipse debugger to figure this out

Comment: The second "if" statement in updateBoard()

Comment: Work backwards from there: *why* did it do what you didn't expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the following condition check:

```
if(ship1[i][0] == userInput[0] && ship1[i][1] == userInput[1]) {
    board[userInput[0]][userInput[1]] = "|!";
    if(userInput[1] == 7) {
        board[userInput[0]][userInput[1]] = "|!|";
    }
} else {
    board[userInput[0]][userInput[1]] = "|X";
    if(userInput[1] == 7) {
        board[userInput[0]][userInput[1]] = "|X|";
    }
}
```

If the user gives co-ordinates that match with `ship1[0][0]` and `ship[0][1]`, it assigns `!` to it but the loop continues and next two ship1 array values won't match thereby resetting it to `X`

The fix is to `break` out of the loop when the match is found.

```
if(ship1[i][0] == userInput[0] && ship1[i][1] == userInput[1]) {
    board[userInput[0]][userInput[1]] = "|!";
    if(userInput[1] == 7) {
        board[userInput[0]][userInput[1]] = "|!|";
    }
    break; // that's it!
}
```

Comment: haha damnit, I hate when its something so small and basic. Thank you for taking the time to look through my code